# How can I set the maximum execution time for a PHP script?

Tags: php, apache, execution-time

I would like to change the maximum execution time for a PHP script. In the script I have tried

```
ini_set("max_execution_time", "1000");
```

and

```
set_time_limit(1000);
```

together and separately.

I also added this line to .htaccess:

```
php_value max_execution_time 1000
```

php.ini has safemode off and the Apache server has the flag `AllowOverride All`. What must I do to get the server to allow a longer execution time?

Comment: have you tried setting it right in the php.ini file?

Comment: Apache's AllowOverride has nothing to do with PHP settings.

Comment: http://br.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php try set and after get the value to check it...

Comment: I forgot to mention that I put a `php_value max_execution_time 1000` in `.htaccess`, which is why I mentioned AllowOverride.

Comment: Can you describe the exact nature of the problem you are experiencing?  Is it timing out?  If so, after so long?  Does it happen to be exactly 300 seconds?

Comment: I want to run a script that takes an exceedingly long time to run, it starts running and the results can be seen, however, it stops running after approximately thirty seconds and returns error 500, although I haven't ever tested the exact time. As for setting it in php.ini because it is just one script and not the whole site.

Comment: Are you sending requests directly to apache?  Proxies may time out even if apache doesn't.  What do you get if you run `var_dump(ini_get('max_execution_time'), ini_get('safe_mode'));` after your call to `set_time_limit(1000);` ?

Answer (score 7):

Setting the variable in the ini file works for me:

```
max_execution_time = 1000;
```

set_time_limit() should work as well, as long as it's not in safe mode.

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking for an Apache2-directive to use in .htaccess or the configuration of one VirtualHost, you probably need php_admin_value:

```
php_admin_value max_execution_time 1000
```

AFAIK this only works with mod_php

Comment: is there a security issue modifying this directive in the Virtual Host ?

Comment: I wouldn't think so. Basically there is a difference between php_admin_value and php_value, the latter permits ini_set() to change the value, the former doesn't. see https://ma.ttias.be/php-php_value-vs-php_admin_value-and-the-use-of-php_flag-explained/.
You might want to be careful about allowing long runtimes in a whole VirtualHost though. Maybe use it inside a <Location> tag to be more granular.

Comment: Can you tell me what to write using the location tag ?

Comment: Have a look at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#location

Answer (score -2):

**Note:** This hack only to run a particular script for a certain time.

Generally you should change php setting.

So
In run time you can set

```
set_time_limit($seconds); // 0 for unlimited
```

at the beginning of a script.