# How long can a php code execute?

Tags: php, loops

I dont know if its the right question.

The thing is that, I have a list of users and their emails stored in my database.

Now I want to send a email to all of them with the help of a loop and setting a time interval delay (may be 5-10 seconds ).

```
foreach($users as $user){
     //code to send the email
}
```

I roughly have around 50 users. So will the code execute until the loop will complete? I mean is it a correct way to do?

What if I have hundreds or even thousands of users in future?

Comment: Then you must do the operation by lots ;]

Comment: whydo you pause the loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default max execution time is `30` seconds. You can easily modify this by going to your `php.ini` file and changing `max_execution_time` option.

If you wish to modify max execution time within your PHP script, you can use this function: `set_time_limit ( int $seconds )`, you can also revert these changes later.

```
//Settings time limit to 0 will make the script execute without time limit(see comments).
set_time_limit (0);

foreach($users as $user){
     //code to send the email
}

set_time_limit (30);
```

Comment: This just applies for active time. If you call `sleep()`, the time while it is waiting will not be counted.

Comment: if you set time limit to 0  ex: `set_time_limit (0)` it will run with no time limit

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php

By default the max_execution_time is 30 seconds. But I don't understand why you would want to stall a script for 5-10 seconds for every user when you're sending an e-mail. You may want to look at a cron job instead.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is belong to server config for maximum time execute. You can read here [How can I set the maximum execution time for a PHP script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638484/php-maximum-execution-time-for-script)