# WORDPRESS - "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in [...]/web/content/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 178"

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a custom post type in my WordPress site and I filled it with the ACF Plugin. When I want to display a page from my custom post type in front page, it takes a long time and I get a 500 error:

> Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in [...]/web/content/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 178

Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164930/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to improve the performance of your code through caching, etc.
You can also increase the "maximum execution time" for PHP scripts as described here: [How can I set the maximum execution time for a PHP script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638484/how-can-i-set-the-maximum-execution-time-for-a-php-script)

Comment: Thanks you! I did this. My page load correctly now but It takes a long time again... I don't understand because I had two other custom post type which load correctly but this one no...