# Apache shows a blank page when the response is too long

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to make a json call to get a big size of data, but when the result is too long I face a blank page with code response 200 which is confusing, see bellow apache access log:

```
10.142.20.26 - - [22/Jun/2020:21:04:10 +0200] "GET /test.php?_=1592852650343 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

When I limit the numbers of rows in the results it shows up perfectly.

I changed the output_buffering value to 10000, but still facing the same problem.

Comment: What does your PHP log show? Sounds like you are either [running out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1425138/6089612), or [running out of time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5638484/6089612)?  In both cases there are short term workarounds/hacks you can do, but probably you should be thinking about how to break the results up into pages?

Comment: That's what driving me crazy, there's nothing in the PHP/Apache error log file.
Memory is well configured 512mb on 16Gb and the time is 300sec, the blank page show up after less than 5secondes